# Devise email only signup - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-confirmable

Within a rails app i'm working on. I'm trying to add the ability for users to signup simply by entering their email address and then confirming their account via the confirmation email. I don't want the user to have to enter in any password. **How would I go about doing this?**

This example is useful, but requires for the user to enter a password: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Email-only-sign-up

**Should I just automatically use one password for all users?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devise is built for **authentication**, which is either a password, or a quick check with a social network that this is actually the person they claim to be. The email address is used as **identification**.

If you just want to *identify* a person by their email, I suggest you create your own system for it. You can even add some of the Devise features in if you like. First, create a `User` model with an email attribute:

```
rails generate model User email:string
```

Once you've migrated the database, create a controller for it:

```
rails generate controller users
```

Then create a `Session` model and let each `User` create sessions by logging in. There'll be plenty of great tutorials on the web of how to create a system like this. Writing helper methods like `current_user` or `user_signed_in?` should be quite easy too.

Now for the last point, if you want people to sign in after they signed up using the email confirmation, how will you make sure that it is actually the same person signing in as the person who confirmed the email? Any malicious user could simply use an already confirmed account to sign in, unless you have to do an email confirmation every time you sign in...

So while you can do the above, I would seriously recommend to have some kind of authentication, whether it be with a password, or using [OmniAuth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) to connect to social networks. There's a railscast for that [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZUmcDioUTNk).

Comment: It would be useful to link to some "great tutorials on the web" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would help you, but based on the simplicity of the authentication process, I would suggest not to use Devise at all. You can just create an action in your `SessionsController`, which will compare the `params[:email]` (or however you are calling it in your app) against the emails listed in the `UsersTable`.